# How to do an 8-hour road trip with a husky puppy?

Tags: dogs, safety, medicines, travel, crate

I will be travelling with a female **Siberian Husky puppy** in about a month from now, and by then my pup would've been **2<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> months old**. I'm a bit uncertain on how I'm going to do this; I've crawled the Internet to find resources, but they're too general and I believe this is the best place still to ask this specific question to pet owners who have done similar, based on knowledge and experience.

I will try to be as objective as possible and will also accept the most objective answer.  Here goes:

**Trip Details:**

1. I live in the Philippines, it's tropical country, but so far most huskies living here have adapted to the kind of climate. (But not direct sunlight of course).
2. The road is 330 kilometers (about 205 miles). Partly dirt road, partly asphalt. A little climb from here and there.
3. Trip usually takes about 8-9 hours at an average of 50-60kph with moderate traffic.
4. I ride a Toyota Avanza, a mini SUV (about 7 seats), A little cramped up, but good.
5. I drive alone, no one will be with me (that kind of makes it a problem).

**Question:**

I'm a little paranoid, but I really want to do this correctly and safely (both for me and the puppy). **So, how do we survive this kind of trip?** Some questions I would like to ask would be:

1. Pet crate or should I fold the seats and let her roam free inside the car? Or should she be in the front seat, or maybe on top of my lap while I drive?
2. Medications? Do they ever get dizzy? Or something similar, perhaps?
3. Food? Should I feed her before the trip? If so, then how long before the trip? Should I feed her along the way or not? At how much time intervals?
4. How often should we go for stops?
5. Other details I might miss?

Thanks!

Comment: We recently did a good 5 hour drive picking up our 8 week old Shetland Sheepdog, who is now 3.5months. We stopped probably three times for him, he was so small he came home in a plastic tub :) lined with newspaper. Since there were four of us in the Kuga (suv as well) he was between two people who could check on him and comfort him. Since you're solo I'd say a crate, with regular stops to check on her, make sure she's ok, hasn't soiled the crate (be prepared for plenty of that over 8-9 hours) we gave pup a few bits of food and water every stop if he wanted it. Don't be fussed if they don't!

Comment: @muffin You should have a look at that  answer: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9313/should-we-crate-our-puppy-during-their-first-car-ride/9314#9314

Comment: Can you take the pup on short rides prior to the long trip?

Comment: no not really... i kind of going to pick her up at my breeder's then travel the 8 hour road to home.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is part of [Pet's Spring Cleaning Campaign](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/spring-cleaning-campaign-on-pets-se). This question is old, but this answer will still help people with the same problem.

---

> 1. Pet crate or should I fold the seats and let her roam free inside the car? Or should she be in the front seat, or maybe on top of my lap while I drive?

**Absolutely not on your lap while driving.** That is a safety hazard. If your dog freaked out and jumped up, you would crash your car.

The safest thing for you and your puppy to do would be to secure them in a travel crate in the backseats. If for some reason you decide to take your puppy out of the crate, make sure that the windows are closed and your puppy is wearing a harness or collar **¹**.

Your dog might also not enjoy the car because of stress or motion sickness. It is important that they do, because I suspect that this will not be the last time they ride in a vehicle. Associate the car with pleasant things such as treats and praise. Let your dog sniff the car and play in it, and start small with driving.

While driving, you can lower the windows (but the dog should *never* be allowed to stick body parts out at first). Regulate the car's temperature and provide exercise before driving. Limit food and water before the car to stop motion sickness  **²**.

> 2. Medications? Do they ever get dizzy? Or something similar perhaps?

Dogs do occasionally get motion sickness, which is fine. It is best to stop it by following section one of this answer's instructions, but if it is not working after several months, consult your trained and licensed vet. They may subscribe you over the counter medications for your dog **³**.

> 3. Food? Should I feed her before the trip? if then how long before the trip? Should I feed her along the way or not? At how much time intervals?

Feed your dog and give them water before the trip. Also, stop while driving, get out, and hydrate and feed your dog (feeding in a moving car will give your dog motion sickness) **⁴**.  Feed your dog at regular feeding times, once at breakfast (around 6-9am but YMMV), once at lunch (11-1:30pm but YMMV), and dinner (5:30-8pm but YMMV). Hydrate your dog more often.

> 4. How often should we go for stops?

Pretty often. Your puppy will need to go to the bathroom every hour for every month of age because their bladder is still small **⁵**. I assume your puppy is eight weeks old (the normal time to get a puppy **⁶**) which means that by every two hours you should stop so he can relieve himself. Also, if this is your puppy's first time in the car, I recommend stopping every 30 minutes at first, and then every hour (or shorter) for fresh air and to stretch his legs.

Be careful not to go to highly visited places, such as rest stops or dog parks, because there is a large risk of [Parovirus](https://www.akc.org/expert-advice/health/parvo-in-dogs/#:%7E:text=What%20Is%20Parvo%3F,spread%20through%20the%20canine%20population.), which is fatal to dogs. It is found in a dog's stool and can last on outdoor surfaces for huge periods of time, sometimes several years **⁷**. Find a quiet spot, preferably away from civilization, for your puppy to relieve himself.

Eventually, your dog will get vaccinated against Parvovirus (from 14-16 weeks **⁸**), but for now, be extra careful.

> 5. Other details I might miss?

Not really. Simply watch your dog. Drive slow. Say kind words to them **⁹**. Give them lots of love and treats. Call a vet if something seems off.
Good luck!

**Sources:**

Section 1.

- ¹  <sub>[www.thepuppyacademy.com](https://www.thepuppyacademy.com/blog/2020/2/24/how-to-train-your-puppy-for-car-rides#:%7E:text=You%27ll%20need%20to%20secure,a%20possible%20distraction%20while%20driving)</sub>
- ²  <sub>[www.akc.org](https://www.akc.org/expert-advice/training/ask-trainers-get-dog-ride-car/)</sub>

Section 2.

- ³  <sub>[pets.webmd.com](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/dogs-and-motion-sickness#1)</sub>
- ³  <sub>[pets.webmd.com](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/dogs-and-motion-sickness#2)</sub>

Section 3.

- ⁴  <sub>[pets.webmd.com](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/guide/how-to-travel-with-your-dog#1)</sub>

Section 4.

- ⁵  <sub>[www.humanesociety.org](https://www.humanesociety.org/resources/how-house-train-your-dog-or-puppy#:%7E:text=Establish%20a%20routine&text=Generally%20speaking%2C%20a%20puppy%20can,guaranteed%20to%20have%20an%20accident)</sub>
- ⁶  <sub>[dogtime.com](https://dogtime.com/puppies/1445-puppy-when-to-bring-home-dunbar#:%7E:text=Eight%20weeks%20of%20age%20has,puppy%20class%20and%20dog%20parks)</sub>
- ⁷  <sub>[pethelpful.com](https://pethelpful.com/dogs/How-Long-Does-Dog-Parvo-Last-in-Your-Home-or-Yard)</sub>
- ⁸  <sub>w[ww.avma.org](https://www.avma.org/resources-tools/pet-owners/petcare/canine-parvovirus#:%7E:text=Puppies%20should%20receive%20a%20dose,is%20up%2Dto%2Ddate)</sub>

Section 5.

- ⁹  <sub>[www.rover.com](https://www.rover.com/blog/show-love-dog-language/)</sub>