# Taking a new puppy out

Tags: dogs, safety, psychology, travel

I really need some advice please.

I am picking up a French bull dog puppy a few days before Christmas. The day after I pick her up, I have to go to family's house for a family meal, which is about 90 minutes away. I can't skip it, as one of the family members we only see once every few years has come over this year.

I was going to bring the puppy with us for the day to our families house. We have a pet carrier we can travel with. OR she could sit on a family member's lap in the of the car to feel more comfortable, as we wouldn't of had time to do crate training.

I did request to pick her up a week later and the breader said she can't hold her for me for that long, as someone else will probably purchase her by then.

Is it a bad idea to take a puppy I have just purchased to see family?

Thank you, any advice would be greatly appreciated, as this would be our first pet.

Comment: If you pay for the pup (now), or put down a deposit, will the breeder hold it for you until the day after your family event? I would think this wouldn't be such a big favor.to expect them to grant. Just get a reciept of the arrangement, document it with photos and take a collar with you so that you can put it on the specific dog you are purchasing.

Comment: Related (unanswered) question [How to do an 8-hour road trip with a husky puppy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/9423/13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment that gave some advice on talking to the breeder. I think it's worth asking if you could pay the breeder a down payment before picking up your puppy. Explain your situation and that you don't want to overwhelm the puppy on her first day with you. See what the breeder says.

If it's not possible to avoid, it should be okay to take her to the party as long as there are no other animals there that she could get sick from since she is young and not yet fully vaccinated. You should also talk to the family members hosting the party and make sure that they are okay with a puppy coming over who won't be house trained yet.

If you do have to take her, here are some tips:

- Find a quiet place where she can lie down and make sure it is comfortable. Her crate would be perfect for this if you can set it up in a corner. Take the door off of it for the evening so that there's no chance of it hurting her accidentally. Make sure it has plenty of padding and something that smells like you or (even better) her mom. When you first get there, set it up and show her where it is.
- Take her outside more than you think she needs. Young puppies may need to go to the bathroom as frequently as every hour, especially if they are excited or nervous. Make sure she pees and poops before your car ride, and plan to stop in the middle of the trip to drink some water, eat a snack, and then wait 20-30 minutes for her to need to use the bathroom again before getting back in the car. When you get to the party, make absolutely sure that she pees before going inside. And set timers for yourself so that you take her out every hour and a half or so throughout the party. When you take her outside, don't give up even if she doesn't seem to need to go. Instead, offer her some water and then walk her in a small area until she pees. This will reduce the likelihood of an accident in your family's house.
- Bring cleaning supplies. Even with the most careful strategy, she is probably going to have at least one accident while she's there or in the car. Bring your own cleaning supplies in a bag and know where they are so that you can be on top of cleaning up the mess (you don't want your great aunt stepping in it by accident).
- Find out if there's a good place that she can be kept in the house, and if it's possible to get baby gates or a small pen to keep her there. If she can stay in the kitchen or even a bathroom when you aren't able to be actively watching her (such as during dinner), that would be helpful. Don't close her in a room by herself, but set up a baby gate in the doorway so that she can't wander around and get into trouble.
- Watch her like a hawk. She should never be in a room without you or someone else who is actively supervising her.
- Watch for signs of stress or overexcitement. Barking, shaking, jumping, or panting could all be signs that it's time for her to take a break from the action. Bring her to her quiet place in the corner or take her outside for some calm snuggle time out of the noise.

Good luck! And congratulations on your new family member!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is going to be new to the puppy.  A car ride is not much different than a new home.  I brought my puppy home on a 4 hour ride.

Try and get a blanket or rug from the litter for her to smell.

Give the puppy a safe place to sleep and do not wake her up.